# Jest is unable to find alias modules

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, ts-jest, tsx

I am getting the configuration error, when running a test through Jest. The path for the module is correct. It's leading to the correct directoy on clicking the path on vs code. Here is the error,

```
Could not locate module @myPackage/button mapped as:

Systempath\projectpath\node_modules\@myPackage\button

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^@myPackage\/(.*)$/": "Systempath\projectpath\node_modules\@myPackage\button\$1"
  },
  "resolver": null
}
```

This is my jest.config.js,

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "./"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@myPackage/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@myPackage/$1",
    "^lib/(.*)": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
    prefix: '<rootDir>/src',
  },
};
```

I have tried updating jest and I have tried various regex for moduleNameMapper and it's still not working.Thanks!